# Empty text in a spark RichText

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm building the contents of a RichText control:

```
private function buildLabelTextElements():void
        {
            beforeResult=new SpanElement(); 
            beforeResult.color=0x000000; 
            beforeResult.fontWeight=FontWeight.NORMAL;
            searchResult=new SpanElement(); 
            searchResult.color=0x9C0836;
            searchResult.fontWeight=FontWeight.BOLD;
            afterResult=new SpanElement(); 
            afterResult.color=0x000000; 
            afterResult.fontWeight=FontWeight.NORMAL;
            var paragraphElement:ParagraphElement=new ParagraphElement();
            paragraphElement.addChild(beforeResult); 
            paragraphElement.addChild(searchResult);
            paragraphElement.addChild(afterResult);
            var textFlow:TextFlow=labelField.textFlow;
            textFlow.addChild(paragraphElement);
            /*var controller:ContainerController=new ContainerController(
                    labelField);
            textFlow.flowComposer.addController(controller);*/
            textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
            //labelField.textFlow=textFlow;
        }
```

Then in another function I'm changing the text in `beforeResult`,`searchResult` and `afterResult`, but for some reason the text I'm getting in the control is empty! What am I missing? I can add the code that changes the text if it can help find the problem, but basically it's just `beforeResult.text=...` and then `labelField.textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: as far as i can see in your code, nothing binds the paragraph to your label, so there is no reasons you see anything... BTW, to ensure it is the update that does not work, try to set a default text when you initialize the result fragments

Comment: But I have: `var textFlow:TextFlow=labelField.textFlow;textFlow.addChild(paragraphElement);`. Doesn't it make the paragraph bound to the label's text flow?

Comment: yes but it is not updated automatically, it is the controller that is responsible of that. uncomment `new ContainerController...` and `addController` and retry

Comment: Still not working, only shows the initial text I gave it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be doing this in the wrong way. Instead of trying to use the existing `TextFlow` object that is assigned to the `Label`, make a brand new `TextFlow` object, and then set that on the `Label`. This is the pattern I recall seeing everywhere, and that I know has worked well in the past:

So instead of:

```
var textFlow:TextFlow=labelField.textFlow;
```

Do:

```
var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
```

Then, after you have populated the `TextFlow` with text, assign the `TextFlow` to the label:

```
labelField.textFlow=textFlow;
```

It may be possible to do it the original way, but you'd have to dig into the internals of the `Label` and/or `TextFlow` classes to determine why it isn't working.